# Need help to convert excel formula to Javascript logic

Tags: javascript, excel, math, angular6

I have a dynamic pricing table where the cost per item changes with the number of items selected.

[see the excel pricing table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxprS.png)

The formula takes the first item and multiplies by quantity, but the rest of the calculation works by adding the number or items-price based on the quantity

```
(1 * 17 = 17),
(17 + 17 = 24),
(17 + 17 + 17 = 51)
```

I had a different formula written in JavaScript but it doesn't calculate the same way so I'm getting different values.

```
let itemPrice:number;
let tier1 = 17;
let tier2 = 15;
let tier3 = 13;
let tier4 = 11;
let tier5 = 9;
let tier6 = 7;
let tier7 = 6;


selectDevices(e: MatSliderChange) {
    this.selectedCount.Items = e.value;
    this.itemPrice = this._getItemPrice(e.value);

    this.invoice.itemPriceTotal =
      this.selectedCount.Items * this.itemPrice;

}

private _getItemPrice(items?: number) {
    let itemPrice = this.tier1;
    if (devices < 5) {
     itemPrice = this.tier1;
    }
    if (devices > 4 && devices < 9) {
     itemPrice = this.tier2;
    }
    if (devices > 8 && devices < 13) {
     itemPrice = this.tier3;
    }
    if (devices > 12 && devices < 17) {
     itemPrice = this.tier4;
    }
    if (devices > 16 && devices < 21) {
     itemPrice = this.tier5;
    }
    if (devices > 20 && devices < 25) {
        itemPrice = this.tier6;
    }
    if (devices > 24) {
         itemPrice = this.tier7;
    }
    return itemPrice;
}
```

When the slider changes the price gets calculated using the functions above, but the result is different because its only multiplying the quantity by the price, but it needs to calculate first 4 at tier1 price, the next 4 at price tier2 + previous 4 at tier1 price. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: The javascript code assumes all items have the same price (i.e. same tier), but only items in the same tier have the same price. Simplest (and inefficient) way to modify this code might be to accumulate the total price with a for-loop.

Comment: Yes, that was the original price calculation, the item would have a single tier price that would fluctuate based on the number of items. But it need to be more of a logarithmic scale so that successive prices graduations represent values that are in an equal ratio.

Comment: the excel example is how it should be calculated, the original would simply multiply quantity * price, and price would be determined by number of items selected, as it is in the code section __getItemPrice_ (that's what i currently have). Basically up to 4 items = 17 per item, 5-8(n) items = 4*17+n*15 , 9-12(n) items = 4*17+4*15+n*13 and so on

Comment: Not n*15 but (n-4)*15. And yes this is what I meant - the javascript code treats all items as having the same price which is incorrect.